# Resources folder not being included in target folder on Android Studio building project

Tags: android-studio, resources, building

I have this files structure for a Java module of an Android project on Android Studio:

```
src
  +  main
       +  java
            + (several folders and source files)
       +  resources
            + nad
                + (several text files)
```

The issue is that `nad` folder is not being copied into `target/classes/` folder when I build the project in Android Studio.
`nad` folder is marked as `resource` on:
`Project Structure` window -> `Modules` -> `Sources`

I have other similar project which is correctly copying the `nad` folder into `target`.

I can't find out which configuration option I must use. Any idea?

Comment: did you get the answer

Comment: No. [this text to fix the minimum chars limit on comments]

Comment: Thanks :)  [this text to fix the minimum chars limit on comments]